# Nifi CSVSetRecordWriter problems

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-nifi, quoting

I try to transform json to csv using UpdateRecord processor with updating record.

My input json can contains fields with `|` and `"`. In the output csv file I want to use `|` as field delimeter and `"` for quotiong all fields.

So, example for input json file:

```
{"field1": "value1", 
 "id": "11112", 
"desc1": "description Text \""
}
```

I get the following result:

```
"value1"|"11112"|"description Text ""
```

Expected result:

```
"value1"|"11112"|"description Text \""
```

Property of CSVRecordSetWriter:

[image: sv]

What can I do to add a `\` before the quotes in the values

Also I have a problem if `\` in field. (such as `"example str\"`). I expect `example str\\"`, but this is not true.